# emacs plugins for web development

Tags: emacs, plugins, installation

What are the best plugins for emacs if you want to use it for web development?

Comment: Do you mean HTML or XHTML? nXHTML mode is apparently quite good for XHTML but it doesn't support HTML at all. I'm quite keen to find a good setup for HTML.

Comment: @Singletoned, anything typical, including regular HTML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in the comments [nXhtml](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html) is an addon to Emacs for editing XHTML, PHP and similar things. It is not very well-known, but it looks like at least Drew Yates has found it useful:

```
nXML mode and the subsequent nXHTML mode for emacs are godsends ...
```

And that was before the developer fixed all the bugs ... ;-)

Most of this is stolen from the project's site, but I most certainly think that nxhtml-mode contains everything essential for web development in it. There are also stuff like the legacy html-mode. css-mode, [php-mode](http://php-mode.sourceforge.net/)(the last two are part of nxhtml-mode). I'm not sure about [espresso-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JavaScriptMode)(which currently is the best javascript mode around). There are also cperl-mode for perl development, ruby-mode - you name it, we've got it.

Comment: I installed it and it looks good. However, is there a way preventing emacs from loading it on startup and just loading it if needed. In particular, I'd like to be able to open an `php` (or whatever) file and stay in normal `php-mode` (or whatever mode). Then, I'd like to be able to optionally activate nxhtml-mode *after* opening the file (with recognition of PHP/html areas). Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Steve Yegge's [js2-mode](http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/).

Answer (score 5):

Not specifically for web development but don't forget [Yasnippet](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet) (or another template / skeleton / snippet system).

I wouldn't be able to stay sane when working on XSLT (still somewhat related to webdev nowadays?) without it. Typing `xcho<TAB>` inserts:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$1">
    $0
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    $2
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

with the cursor initially standing at $1 (the $* parts aren't displayed), then after pressing `<TAB>` again at $2 and finally at $0.

I don't have any specific HTML examples but the snippets are easy to make.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a mode with automatic indentation of mixed-language code.

So I wrote a minor mode that handles PHP/XHTML/JS/CSS. I dare say it does it quite well. You can download it from [github](https://github.com/sabof/web-mixed-indentation-mode)